# PHP Bad Request in Curl on SOAP interface of http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/PlaceSearch

Tags: php, curl, soap, bad-request

I am trying to call the url using curl in php. I get a BAD REQUEST error .
if someone can help me,I do not get what the problem is

Their "recipe" is as follows: http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch (look at soap 1.1)

The code I have is:

```
  <?      
        // xml data    
        $soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
              $soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n";
              $soap_request .= " <soap:Body>\n";
              $soap_request .= "  <PlaceSearch xmlns=\"http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/\">\n";
              $soap_request .= "  <xml><PlaceSearchRequest><Username>SERUNCD</Username><Password>TA78UNC</Password><PlaceType>Cities</PlaceType><Language>en</Language></PlaceSearchRequest></xml>\n";
              $soap_request .= "   </PlaceSearch>\n";
              $soap_request .= "  </soap:Body>\n";
              $soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";

          // heder    
               $header = array(
    "POST /services/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: wl.filos.com.gr",
    "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
    "SOAPAction: \"http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/PlaceSearch\""
  );


        // call currl  
            $soap_do = curl_init();
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch" );
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
                      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
                      curl_getinfo($soap_do, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
                    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

                     $output = curl_exec($soap_do);
                         $info = curl_getinfo($soap_do);
                           print_r(curl_getinfo($soap_do)) ;
                      if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
                        $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
                        curl_close($soap_do);
                        print $err;
                      } else {
                        curl_close($soap_do);
                        print 'Operation completed without any errors  <br />';
                      }


                            echo "The server responded: <br />";
                            echo   " " .  $info['http_code'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Try to remove POST, Host, Content type and Content length from headers. This information there are in curl_set_ opt already.

Comment: Does not work.
now reports an error The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't have a WSDL for the SOAP interface of the www.cyberlogic.gr webservice, you won't benefit from using it compared with the other methods, e.g. the GET method:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Example for cyberlogic.gr GET webservice
 */

// create the request XML
$request            = new SimpleXMLElement("<PlaceSearchRequest/>");
$request->Username  = "SERUNCD";
$request->Password  = "TA78UNC";
$request->PlaceType = "Cities";
$request->Language  = "en";

$url    = "http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx/PlaceSearch";
$result = simplexml_load_file($url . "?xml=" . urlencode($request->asXML()));
if ($result) {
    // process result
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($result->Response->Cities->City as $City) {
        printf("#%03d: %s (%s)\n", $count++, $City->CityName, $City["city_id"]);
    }
}
```

This example also shows how to access the city-id attribute which was something not easily possible with standard result parsing and mapping of PHP's **SoapClient**. As the result type remains undefined anyway, doing this in **SoapClient** isn't worth the steps it would need to take.

Example Output:

```
#000: Achladies (545)
#001: Afitos (338)
#002: Agia Paraskevi (548)
...
#142: Volos town (473)
#143: Vourvourou (420)
#144: Vrachos- Loutsa (922)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8" in your header line?

Comment: nope error string 'The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.'

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to use [PHP SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) for [SOAP request](http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch) OR [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for [HTTP POST or GET request](http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch).

Here is your code:

```
$soap_request  = 'xml='.urlencode(trim('
<PlaceSearchRequest>
    <Username>SERUNCD</Username>
    <Password>TA78UNC</Password>
    <PlaceType>Cities</PlaceType>
    <Language>en</Language>
</PlaceSearchRequest>
'));

$header = array(
    'POST /services/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: wl.filos.com.gr',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($soap_request),
);

$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');


$output = curl_exec($soap_do);
$info = curl_getinfo($soap_do);

if (curl_exec($soap_do) === FALSE)
{
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
}
else
{
    curl_close($soap_do);
}

echo 'The server responded: '.$info['http_code']."\n";
echo 'Output: '.$output;
echo "\n";
```

Run it in terminal with `php your_code.php` for example.

Here is output for current XML string data:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: Thanks for your help ..
but still this instead of a list of cities reporting the error ..

http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch
if in the "Value" put <PlaceSearchRequest> <Username> SERUNCD </ Username> <Password> TA78UNC </ Password> <placetype> Cities </ placetype> <language> en </ language> </ PlaceSearchRequest>
get the list .. do I need this ..

Comment: anyone,,
How can I take data
http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch

if in the "Value" typing
<PlaceSearchRequest> <Username> SERUNCD </ Username> <Password> TA78UNC </ Password> <placetype> Cities </ placetype> <language> en </ language> </ PlaceSearchRequest>

   click the 'Invoke' button, get the xml ..
 
please help

Comment: No id of the city, but only the name of the town .. or am I wrong watch

Comment: There is id of the city: `<City city_id="784" province_id="233"><CityName>Agia Triada</CityName></City>`. Give me a time.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP interface of the www.cyberlogic.gr webservice for the PlaceSearch requires you to pass the xml parameter properly encoded - otherwise you'll get a 400 Bad Request response.

This is normally done best by using the XML library of your choice, here I do that with *SimpleXML* which is pretty handy for your use-case:

```
// create the request XML
$request            = new SimpleXMLElement('<PlaceSearchRequest/>');
$request->Username  = 'SERUNCD';
$request->Password  = 'TA78UNC';
$request->PlaceType = 'Cities';
$request->Language  = 'en';
```

Next to creating correct XML for the parameter to be passed, the parameter itself needs to be properly encoded as well. As this involves some values configured, first of all define the data needed for the whole operation:

```
$soapUrl   = "http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx";
$namespace = "http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/";
$action    = "PlaceSearch";
```

and then use the `$request` object just created to turn it into the needed SOAP parameter. It is important here, that the XML encoding is applied correctly as well. Again, this should be done with the XML library of your choice, here I do that with *DOMDocument*:

```
// create the soap variable
$var = new DOMDocument();
$var->appendChild($var->createElementNS($namespace, 'xml'));
$var->documentElement->nodeValue = $request->asXML();
$soapVar = new SoapVar($var->saveXML($var->documentElement), XSD_ANYXML);
```

Note that the XML is properly assigned as XML to the `nodeValue`. This is important to create a valid request.

Now as `$soapVar` has been created, all it needs it so setup the **SoapClient**:

```
// create soap client in non-WSDL mode
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => $soapUrl,
    'uri'      => $namespace
));
```

And then do the request:

```
// place soap call
$result = $client->__soapCall(
    $action, array($soapVar), array('soapaction' => "$namespace$action")
);
```

And that's it already. Note that the API you have has some XML problems, namely it makes use of an XML element with the tag-name "xml" which is reserved and not allowed. That's also a sign that you should take extra care when you need to trouble-shoot your webservice requests. As curl can only give you a 400 Bar request, **SoapClient** does actually return much better error messages which help a lot to get things started.

What's left is the processing of the return value, here exemplary:

```
// process result
foreach ($result->PlaceSearch->Response->Cities->City as $i => $City) {
    printf("#%03d: %s\n", $i, $City->CityName);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
#000: Achladies
#001: Afitos
#002: Agia Paraskevi
...
#142: Volos town
#143: Vourvourou
#144: Vrachos- Loutsa
```

The code-example in full incl. error handling for the soap request:

```
/**
 * Example for cyberlogic.gr SOAP webservice
 */
$soapUrl   = "http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx";
$namespace = "http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/";
$action    = "PlaceSearch";

// create the request XML
$request            = new SimpleXMLElement('<PlaceSearchRequest/>');
$request->Username  = 'SERUNCD';
$request->Password  = 'TA78UNC';
$request->PlaceType = 'Cities';
$request->Language  = 'en';

// create the soap variable
$var = new DOMDocument();
$var->appendChild($var->createElementNS($namespace, 'xml'));
$var->documentElement->nodeValue = $request->asXML();
$soapVar = new SoapVar($var->saveXML($var->documentElement), XSD_ANYXML);

// create soap client in non-WSDL mode
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => $soapUrl,
    'uri'      => $namespace
));

try {
    // place soap call
    $result = $client->__soapCall(
        $action, array($soapVar), array('soapaction' => "$namespace$action")
    );

    // process result
    foreach ($result->PlaceSearch->Response->Cities->City as $i => $City) {
        printf("#%03d: %s\n", $i, $City->CityName);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo $client->__getLastRequest(); // set 'trace' => true SoapClient option
}
```

Comment: Man can be a little help ..
how to get it and city_id and province_id
<City city_id = "615" province_id = "187">
   <Cityname> Agios Gordis </ cityname>
</ City>
on your example I only got names, but I need the id of the city

Comment: do you know what a variable is? if yes, use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) to look into the structure. As the example shows, it's not only getting names, but also a complete array of all cities as well as every city. Try with `print_r($city);` inside the foreach. For everything use `print_r($result)`;` after the `__soapCall()`.

Comment: If you go to the link
http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch
field "Value" enter an <PlaceSearchRequest> <Username> SERUNCD </ Username> <Password> TA78UNC </ Password> <placetype> Cities </ placetype> <language> en </ language> </ PlaceSearchRequest>
get xml with the name of the city and its id.
But soap does not return the id of the city, just the
http://agency.lastminute-hr.com/stranice/upisi_destinacije_unico.php

Comment: @sale2211: Now I've seen what your issue is with the SOAP result. Unless you can obtain a WSDL it's just much more straight forward to use the GET method of that webservice, [I added another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26705237/367456).

Answer (score 0):

**Done!**

```
$soap_request  = 'xml='.urlencode(trim('
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PlaceSearchRequest>
    <Username>SERUNCD</Username>
    <Password>TA78UNC</Password>
    <PlaceType>Cities</PlaceType>
    <Language>en</Language>
</PlaceSearchRequest>
'));

$header = array(
    'POST /services/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: wl.filos.com.gr',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($soap_request),
);

$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx/PlaceSearch');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');


$output = curl_exec($soap_do);
$info = curl_getinfo($soap_do);

if (curl_exec($soap_do) === FALSE)
{
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
}
else
{
    curl_close($soap_do);
}

echo 'The server responded: '.$info['http_code']."\n";
echo 'Output: '.$output;
echo "\n";
```